# oauth2 spring security with spring session to invalid those users which are inactive for 30 minutes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session, spring-security-rest

After 30 minutes of inactivity means (no request with access token is made),than the session will expire and user need to create token again. But if request is done than again 30 minutes will given from the current time(current time + 30 mins).
How we can achieve this with oauth2 spring security and spring session or any other way with oauth2 spring security.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge. Create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clearity and add  code here

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and implement this method: `public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)`. When you can set a token validity period like this `clients.accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800)`.